# pip installing into .local with compiled binaries for several platforms?

Tags: python, pip

I am using some compiled modules on a cluster where my home directory is shared across a few different architectures. By manually copying files I can have these two version peacefully co-existing:

```
/home/wright/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ImageD11/_cImageD11.cpython-38-powerpc64le-linux-gnu.so
/home/wright/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ImageD11/_cImageD11.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

Is there a way to get pip to leave the previously compiled version(s) in place when installing for another architecture?

Comment: My advice is to avoid installing into `~/.local/` using `pip install --user`, especially when the `$HOME` is on a shared drive. Instead use separate (not shared) virtual environments for different platforms.

Answer (score 0):

This just needed the `-I` or `--ignore-installed` for pip. It then ignores the installed version(s) and writes over the top. Just re-run it for each architecture, platform and python version you need.

Other useful options may be `--force-reinstall` and almost always you'll need `--no-deps` as well as remembering `python -m pip install pip --upgrade` before starting.

Like this: you can run a code together with the system python, or any of the other venv's you find. Obviously, that code needs to be version tolerant with respect to any dependencies.